# How many harvests do trees and livestock last?

Tags: arche-age

If I plant a tree or livestock (for example, a dairy cow) on land that I own and make sure to harvest the fruit or animal product in a timely manner, how many harvests will that tree or livestock last before dying on average? Is there an age component to determining when a tree or livestock dies or is it strictly random chance after harvesting and the object becomes ripe again?

Comment: I only have anecdotes, but it seemed to me that my geese lived as long as I continued tending to them- they died after a few days of ignoring them (though I also had times where they lived for a long time as my guildmates cared for them while I was away).

Comment: @Delioth: Things do tend to survive for a long time. However, after a resource ripens, it'll occasionally say "dying jujube tree" or "dying dairy cow" or some such. Then you get one last chance to harvest the fruit or product, and then it dies and/or despawns.

Comment: The reason this is relevant is I'm trying to determine how profitable farming my own materials are. But in order to justify the cost of a tree or livestock, I need to be able to estimate how much it can produce over it's life. While I can easily figure out the average quantity of product the resource produces, I don't know how long, on average, the resource will last.